# returning all facet's data in algolia

Tags: c#, search, backend, facet, algolia

Is there a way to return all the facet's data not depending on the search result. fr example I always want to see all authors not just authors for search query "gone with"

I came across Disjunctive Faceting but I don't think this can help it still returns values based on my search term

```
var helper = algoliasearchHelper(
  client,
  // index name
  'hotels', {
    facets: ['facilities'],       // list of conjunctive facets
    disjunctiveFacets: ['stars'], // list of disjunctive facets
    hitsPerPage: 10
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Disjunctive faceting](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/filtering-faceting#disjunctive-faceting) is used to `OR` values.
The `algoliasearchHelper` will actually do multiple search queries at the same time :

- The main one with the query and all refinements. This will populate the results list and the facet values for conjonctive facets/attributes.
- One per disjunctive facet. It includes the query and the refinements of all the facets except the current disjunctive facet. This will populate the facet values list for this facet.

This second type of request is here to be able to list other facets values which, if refined, would have associated results.
We haven't seen use-cases where you'd like the user to get either an empty list of results or an unchanged one if he/she clicked on a facet.

If you'd like to always have the full list of authors, you could probably have it stored in your back-end, always display it, but adapt the counts on each `results` event.